# bootstrap datetimepicker is not working after clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap datetime picker: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

When I clone a time input field then cloned time input field is not working. Do you know why? How can I solve it?

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
   $('#datetimepicker1, #datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      minDate: new Date(),
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
   });

   $('.datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
      minDate: new Date(),
      format: 'hh:mm A',
   });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='input-group date'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control mul_pickup datetimepicker3" name="mul_pickup[0][]" placeholder="Pickup Time">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example for making a clone of the datetimepicker.

I hope this will helful for you.

I made clone on document load. When user click on the ADD NEW button then clone reapply datepicker to the cloned elements so the datepicker applied to the newly added elements.

```js
 $(function () {
  var clone = $('.clone').clone().removeClass('clone');
      $('.clone').removeClass('clone');
      clone = clone.removeClass('clone');
        $('.add-new').click(function(){
        var new_clone = clone.clone();
          // For your solution you need to reapply 
          new_clone.find('.datetimepicker').datepicker({
              format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
              language: "en",
              autoclose: true,
              todayHighlight: true
          });
          $(new_clone).insertAfter('.form-group:last');
        });
        
        $('.datetimepicker').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            language: "en",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
    });
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <h2>Datetimepicker</h2>
  
 </div>
 <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group clone">
                <div class='input-group date datetimepicker' >
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class='add-new btn btn-default'>Add New
        </button>
        
        
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>
```